# Reading a spring boot "jar" and/or changing (injecting a class to) a spring boot fat jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, 7zip

By default, spring-boot builds a "fat" "jar" (not a normal jar).

1. Is it possible to unjar a "fat" spring-boot jar?
2. Is it possible to change a "fat" spring-boot jar?

Obviously, my questions aren't decision problems (although they are formulated as decision problems)- would appreciate an "algorithm", in case the answer is positive.

Thanks!

Comment: by default ? No you have to use the repackage goal to create a boostrap jar. About your questions, which is the goal of doing such operations ?

Comment: Thanks. Example use-cases: decompilation, injecting specific classes and there are more

Comment: when you say change a fat spring spring boot jar what exactly do you mean,Please elaborate  I have even seen people adding class files to a jar using 7Zip.

Comment: It's a zip file, you can unzip it.

Comment: Thanks- in the past I couldn't unzip it with 7zip, but now I've tried again and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: All JARs are essentially zip files with specific file order. Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

Comment: This was turned into a question about 7zip...  "open as an archive" doesn't work for this file in 7zip (even when changing the suffix to .zip), but  7zip->open archive ->zip does work, though I thought that 7zip would infer this from the suffix.